# Javascript popup

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to open this modal DIV from code behind but I am getting error message. Please let me know what's wrong with this.

Here is .aspx code.

```
<div id="modal" runat="server" style="display:none;">
    <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" onClick="Popup.hide('modal')" CausesValidation="False"/>
</div>
```

Code behind

```
       if (!Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("MyScript"))
        {
            string confirmbox = "Popup.showModal('modal');return false;";
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "MyScript", confirmbox, true);
        }
```

Comment: Could you please post what the actual error message says? Just saying that you got one isn't very helpful.

Comment: I am getting "Too many characters in character literal when loading the page.

Comment: That might be an issue with the Popup script itself; FireFox + FireBug might be able to flesh that error source out quickly.

Comment: Is this an error in JavaScript, or an error in the code-behind? C# often throws that error when it sees strings inside single-quotes (like 'modal')

Answer (score 0):

For the error mentioned by you as

```
"Too many characters in character literal when loading the page"
```

You have to use OnClientClick instead of using onClick as it is a ASP.NET Server Control and not a normal HTML5 control.

For the code you have asked for:
Code for opening modal on page load
ASPX Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script>
            function hidePopup()
            {
                document.getElementById('modal').close();
            }
        </script>
</head>
<body  onload="showPopup();">
    <form id="form1" runat="server" >
  <dialog id="modal">
    <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" OnClientClick="hidePopup();return false;"/>
</dialog>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code Behind .CS Code

```
if (!Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("MyScript"))
                {
                    string confirmbox = "function showPopup(){document.getElementById('modal').showModal();}";
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "MyScript", confirmbox, true);
                }
```

Tested on Chrome Version:39.0.2171.99 m , it works perfectly.

With this modal you can also exit the popup using "Esc" key,instead of Close button also.